# Create webinar using citrix api in c#

Tags: c#, citrix

I want to create Webinar in GoToWebinar using Citrix API. I am having following code:

```
public class CreateWebinarTime
{
     public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
     public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}

public class NewWebinar
{
      public string subject { get; set; }
      public string description { get; set; }
      public List<CreateWebinarTime> Times { get; set; }
      public string timeZone { get; set; }
}

string uri = @"https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/[ORGKEY]/webinars";
CreateWebinarTime t = new CreateWebinarTime();
t.StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
t.EndTime = t.StartTime.AddHours(2);
List<CreateWebinarTime> tempList = new List<CreateWebinarTime>();
tempList.Add(t);
var newWebinar = new NewWebinar
{
    subject="Webinar Test",
    description="This is a test webinar.. Will be deleted soon",
    Times = tempList,
    timeZone = "Asia/Calcutta"
};
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = ser.Serialize(newWebinar);

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
client.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("OAuth oauth_token={0}", OauthToken));
string resp = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", json);
```

It is showing me error "The webinar subject, start or end time are missing" even though I am passing value. I am sure there is no problem with subject, so there is problem with time.

The json created is: {"subject":"Webinar Test","description":"This is a test webinar.. Will be deleted soon","Times":[{"StartTime":"/Date(1424233883641)/","EndTime":"/Date(1424241083641)/"}],"timeZone":"Asia/Calcutta"}

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.
Json is case sensititve and I made mistake over there.
Used 'Times' instead of 'times', 'StartTime' instead of 'startTime' and 'EndTime' instead of 'endTime'